# want to assign a multidimensional array in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

**`Language`**: Ionic2.

**`Description`**: The idea is, I try to get data from cloud by using provider. In the home component I call the provider's method and try to assign it's result to the variable. But it does not work.

***`Sample Code for provider's code`***

```
lastValues: any[][] = [[]];

constructor(public http: Http) {}

getLastValues() {
    this.http.get("http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/datasources/" + this.dataSourcaId + "/variables/?token=" + this.ubidotsToken)
        .map(res => res.json().results).subscribe(data => {

        this.lastValues = Array(Math.ceil(data.length / 2));
        let rowNum = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2) {
            this.lastValues[rowNum] = Array(2);

            if (data[i]) {

                this.lastValues[rowNum][0] = data[i].name;
                // console.log(this.lastValues[rowNum][0]);
            }

            if (data[i+1]) {
                this.lastValues[rowNum][1] = data[i+1].name;
            }

            rowNum++;
        }

    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

    return this.lastValues;
}
```

***`Sample code for home component`***

```
export class HomePage {

sensors: any[][];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataService: Data, public platform: Platform) {
}

ionViewDidLoad(){

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.sensors = this.dataService.getLastValues();
    });
}


test() {
    console.log(this.sensors);
    console.log(this.dataService.getLastValues());
}
```

}

In test method, the first command prints empty array and the second the array with the data from cloud. Can't understand what thing i am doing wrong.

Thanks...

Comment: Is someone invoking `test` without waiting for `ionViewDidLoad`'s callback to finish?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that's happening is because you're making an http request but your `return this.lastValues;` does not wait until that http request finishes.

When you call the service the first time, the http request is sent, and immediately you return `this.lastValues` which is empty. The second time you call the service, you make another http request (which, again, does not finish) and again, you immediately return the `this.lastValues` matrix, but this time it's not empty because the first http request ended at some point and the matrix was initialized.

A better way to organize your code and to avoid async issues, would be:

**Provider**

```
lastValues: any[][] = [[]];

constructor(public http: Http) {}

public getLastValues(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/datasources/" + this.dataSourcaId + "/variables/?token=" + this.ubidotsToken)
        .map(res => res.json().results)
        .map(data => {

          this.lastValues = Array(Math.ceil(data.length / 2));
          let rowNum = 0;

          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2) {
            this.lastValues[rowNum] = Array(2);

            if (data[i]) {
                this.lastValues[rowNum][0] = data[i].name;
                // console.log(this.lastValues[rowNum][0]);
            }

            if (data[i+1]) {
                this.lastValues[rowNum][1] = data[i+1].name;
            }

            rowNum++;
          }

          return this.lastValues;
    });
}
```

So basically I'm using the `map(() => {});` function to transform the data, and also returning the `this.http.get()` that will, eventually, return the `lastValues` matrix.

By doing that, instead of subscribing to the `http.get()` in the provider, you can do it in the component code, avoiding issues and bugs just because data is not yet ready.

**Component**

```
export class HomePage {

  sensors: any[][];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataService: Data, public platform: Platform) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){

    this.dataService.getLastValues().subscribe(result => { 
      this.sensors = result;
      console.log(this.sensors);
    }, error => {
      console.log('An error has ocurred: ' + error);
    });
  }


  test() {
    this.dataService.getLastValues().subscribe(result => { 
      this.sensors = result;
      console.log(this.sensors);
    }, error => {
      console.log('An error has ocurred: ' + error);
    });
}
```